# mod_dav_svn loading error on centos 5

Tags: svn, installation, mod-dav-svn

I am trying to install subversion on a centos VPS.
I managed to install subversion and mod_dav_svn and now I am trying to configure them.

I edited httpd.conf and added the lines:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

But this crashes apache on restart:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 1 of
>   /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
>   Syntax error on line 1 of
>   /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_main_global.conf:
>   Cannot load
>   /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
>   into server:
>   /usr/lib64/libsvn_fs_base-1.so.0:
>   undefined symbol: db_create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to fix the error.
It wasnt from not loading dav_module, i forgot to mention i already run httpd - M to see the loaded modules and mod_dav was loaded.

The problem was with Berkeley DB package,

The solution i found is explained here:
[FIX UNDEFINED SYMBOL: DB_CREATE ISSUE WITH MOD SVN DAV AND APACHE 2](http://www.orangecoat.com/how-to/fix-undefined-symbol-dbcreate-issue-with-mod-svn-dav-and-apache-2)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=14586 :

> This error means that you are loading
>   mod_dav_svn into your httpd but you're
>   not loading the mod_dav. Try to add
>   the following line to your httpd.conf
>   modules section:
>
> LoadModule dav_module
>   modules/mod_dav.so

Answer (score 0):

Please add these config entries by yourself. Do not just copy and paste from somewhere. I ran into the same issue and manually adding the entries fixed the problem.